# How to convert InputStream to FileStream?

Tags: java, android, process, streaming

I want convert InputStream to FileStream on Android

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream)stdout;
FileDescriptor fd = fis.getFD();
```

"cmd" is stream command.
Is it impossible?
If possible, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClassLoader#getResource()` instead.

```
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("Resource_Name");
File file = new File(resource.toURI());
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
```

That said, I really don't see any benefit of doing so, or it must be required by a poor helper class/method which requires FileInputStream instead of InputStream. If you can, just use InputStream instead.

Comment: Important, I want FileDescriptor from Process.

Comment: hmm..did you try casting it? By using the method I gave above, see if you can just add a cast to it.